# Recording sound with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-embedded-compact

There is a MVC project needs to run on [Honeywell CV31 Vehicle-Mounted Computer](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/products/computer-devices/vehicle-mounted/thor-cv31)  and the **issue** is ***recording, playing sounds at browser***. Device has `Windows CE 7.0.`

1. I tried to use [Intermec HTML 5](http://www.intermec.com/products/html5/) browser but `audio` tag is not available on it, also tried [ZetaKey](http://zetakey.com/), `Internet Explorer` browsers.
2. Tried to use `Flash` which is not supported.
3. I found `Silverlight` solution but *CE 7.0* supports `Silverlight 3.0` and `Silverlight 3.0` doesn't have media in that version.
4. Tried many kind of external `js` libraries and browser not able to run *Web API*
5. Tried to use `mciSendString`*(winmm.dll*), it works on local fine but not successful on server.

Need to find a solution or a new approach to solve this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing an exe for sound record, by using `PInvoke` library